# Recursive function in x86-assembly

Tags: c, assembly, recursion, x86

I have a method `method(int a, int b)` in x86 assembly code:

```
method:
  pushl  %ebx
  subl   $24 , %esp
  movl   32(%esp ) , %ebx
  movl   36(%esp ) , %edx
  movl   $1 , %eax
  testl  %edx , %edx
  je     .L2
  subl   $1 , %edx
  movl   %edx , 4(%esp )
  movl   %ebx , (%esp )
  call   method
  imull  %ebx , %eax
.L2:
  addl   $24 , %esp
  popl   %ebx
  ret
```

But I just cant wrap my head around its function.

`a` is written on `%ebx`, `b` is written on `%edx`.

`%eax` is initialized with 1.

If `%edx` is not 0, I substract 1 from `%edx` and push `%edx` and `%ebx` on the stack and call `method` again. I just dont understand what it does. And isn't it impossible to reach the line `imull %ebx, %eax`?

I would be really happy, if someone could explain the basic function of this method to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is basically equivalent to following C function:

```
int method(int a, int b)
{
  if (b == 0)
    return 1;

  return method(a, b-1) * a;  
}
```

or closer to the assembly code:

```
int method(int a, int b)
{
  if (b == 0)
    return 1;

  int temp = method(a, b-1);

  return temp * a;  // we do get here when the recursion is over,
                    // the same ways as we get to imull %ebx, %eax
                    // in your assembly code when the recursion is over
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`imull %ebx, %eax` is reached when the recursive call returns.

The function appears to be calculating the power of the input variables (a<sup>b</sup>) via recursion and the value is returned via `%eax`.

The way this works is that the base case is when `b` is 0, and 1 is returned. When `b` > 0, `method(a, b-1) * a` is returned.

Comment: Ok, so if b=0 it just returns `%eax`, which is 1. And if its not 0 it calculates a^b. but why does it multiply `%ebx` with `%eax`? Couldnt it just write the result onto `%eax` via `movl`?

Comment: @mind - it doesn't calculate *a\*b*, it calculates a<sup>b</sup>. For that it multiples the intermediate result in `%eax` by `%ebx` (b).